# how to find distinct pairwise difference between the elements of array?

Tags: time-complexity, space-complexity

I am trying to  reduce the time complexity of a function which finds the distinct difference between elements of array.
i tried it in java

```
`public static ArrayList<Integer>lis=new ArrayList();
public static void diff(int arr[]){
    int n=arr.length;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            int a=arr[i]=arr[j];
            if(lis.contains(a))continue;
            lis.add(a);
        }
    }
    
}`
```

In this it's time complexity is n^2 due to for loops and if at end there are k  integers in arrayList
it will be (n^2)+(k^2).

can anyone suggest a better way?
THANKS in advance :)

Comment: Please, remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: You may use `Set` container for `lis`. And just store `arr` into it. It will improve complexity to `O(n)`.